# How to set parameters in menu Item Joomla Component

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-component

Following is my code.

```
<fields name="request">
    <fieldset name="request">
        <field name="format" type="list" label="COM_CPS_FIELD_FORMAT"
            description="COM_CPS_FIELD_FORMAT_DESC" class="small"
            default="raw"
        >
            <option value="">COM_CPS_FORMAT_HTML</option>
            <option value="raw">COM_CPS_FORMAT_RAW</option>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

When I save the menu with 2nd option it save the url like this `index.php?option=com_cps&view=webservice&format=raw` but when I save the menu with first option it does not remove the `&format=raw` If any one can help me out It would be great.

Comment: may be you have selected default="raw" try to remove or blank it

Comment: probably need to actually set the value on the first option to be `html` not empty: `<option value="html">...`

Comment: @RakeshSharma When I remove the default it work perfactly instead when I create new menu it show me first item as default. I dont want to change the <option>'s places.

Answer (score 0):

Default is defined as what to save if nothing is posted. It works like a Joomla input filter in that it changes what is actually saved as opposed to validation which stops the process and never posts. Therefore you cannot save nothing, since it will always be replaced by the default. Therefore if you want to be able to save blank you must not have a default.

What you may be looking for is a preset, which is a preselected value that can be unselected. Presets and defaults are totally different things although on the surface they appear similar.